# Google Maps API OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps API to geocode locations from asp.net - doing a few queries per day (well under the 2500 limit). This has worked fine for a year and still works on my development server but now I am constantly getting the status returned 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT'.

I assume, but have no way of knowing for sure, that this is because someone else on the same IP address of my host is doing the same and using all the limit.

The geocoding api does not seem to let me use an API key.  If I try to add &key=xxx I get a REQUEST_DENIED error.

How can I identify myself to google as separate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't identify yourself as separate from your co-hosted competitor (for example, by using a key). The reason for this is probably because people would simply use different keys to get multiple allowances.

The only solution is to change your hosting, or switch to client-side geocoding.

Answer (score 0):

Google also limits on the number of request per second, this may be causing the error. Try switching to http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/ usage limit is 50,000 requests per day

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But the application is for UK addresses and in the testing I did Yahoo struggled to get the locations right.